# Matlab: how to find row indices of a matrix satisfying certain requirements?

Tags: matlab, matrix

`A` is a matrix `40 x 10000`. `V1`, `V2` and `V3` are 3 vectors with the same dimension `1 x 50`.

I want to find 3 vectors `W1`, `W2` and `W3` with the same dimension `1 X p` (p: the largest possible p<=40) satisfying the following conditions:

- W1(i), W2(i) and W3(i) belong to A(i,:)
- all the elements of Wk belong to Vk, k=1,2,3

Wk is not a known vector! but Vk are predefined.

So the goal is to find row indices of A that contain Wk, with size(Wk) the largest possible.

example: (I used some character in the matrix to make the example clearer)

```
      95    45    92    41    13     1    84
       a     1     e    89     h    74    52
A=    60    82    17     5    19    44    20
      48    44    40    35    67    93    67
       b    61     f    81     m    46    83
       c    79     g    20     n    41     1

V1 = [51 a 23 11 b 5 c]

V2 = [e g 93 14 22 f 10]

V3 = [81 n 87 h 45 77 m]
```

for this example `p=3` (the largest possible value) so:

```
W1 =[a b c]

W2 =[e f g]

W3 =[h m n]
```

The desired result: A(2,:), A(5,:) and A(6,:).

another example:

if:

```
      95    45    92    41    13     1    84
       a     1     e    89     h    74    52
A=    60    82    17     5    19    44    20
       b    44    40    35    67    93    67
      48    61     f    81     m    46    83
       c    79     g    20     n    41     1

V1 = [51 a 23 11 b 5 c]

V2 = [e g 93 14 22 f 10]

V3 = [81 n 87 h 45 77 m]
```

for this example `p=2` (the largest possible value); because 48 does not belong to V1, and 40 and 67 do not belong to V2 and V3 respectively, so:

```
W1 =[a c]

W2 =[e g]

W3 =[h n]
```

The desired result: A(2,:) and A(6,:).

another example:

if: (if b in A is one column to the right)

```
      95    45    92    41    13     1    84
       a     1     e    89     h    74    52
A=    60    82    17     5    19    44    20
      77     b    40    35    67    93    67
      48    61     f    81     m    46    83
       c    79     g    20     n    41     1

V1 = [51 a 23 11 b 5 c]

V2 = [e g 93 14 22 f 10]

V3 = [81 n 87 h 45 77 m]
```

for this example `p=2` (the largest possible value),  so:

```
W1 =[a c]

W2 =[e g]

W3 =[h n]
```

The desired result: A(2,:) and A(6,:).

another example:

if: (if c in A is one column to the right)

```
      95    45    92    41    13     1    84
       a     1     e    89     h    74    52
A=    60    82    17     5    19    44    20
       b    44    40    35    67    93    67
      48    61     f    81     m    46    83
      88     c     g    20     n    41     1

V1 = [51 a 23 11 b 5 c]

V2 = [e g 93 14 22 f 10]

V3 = [81 n 87 h 45 77 m]
```

for this example `p=1` (the largest possible value); so:

```
W1 =[a]

W2 =[e]

W3 =[h]
```

The desired result: A(2,:).

Comment: Can there be repetitions, like `W1 =[a b c a]`, etc.?

Comment: @Divakar: No, and p is not predefined.

Comment: Can we take the number of vectors (3) as fixed? Or should that be a variable parameter (more difficult)?

Comment: @Divakar: The goal is not to find Wk but finding the row of the matrix A, A(i,:), that contain all Wk(j) for k=1,2,3 and for a given value of j. Wk is just an intermediate step to understanding what we want.

Comment: Do all matches have to be in the same column for each W? What if `b` in `A` is one column to the right?

Comment: @LuisMendo: the nombre of vector V and W is fixed, but p (row number of Wk) is not fixed (unknown value which is determining in the steps of calculating)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to work. The variable `result` gives the set of selected rows (such as `[2 5 6]` or `[2 6]` in your examples). Of course, you could then take `A(result,:)`, or obtain `p` as `numel(result)`.

```
eq1 = any(bsxfun(@eq, A, permute(V1, [1 3 2])), 3); %// does entry of A match V1?
eq2 = any(bsxfun(@eq, A, permute(V2, [1 3 2])), 3); %// ...V2?
eq3 = any(bsxfun(@eq, A, permute(V3, [1 3 2])), 3); %// ...V3?
result = [];
for nr = 1:size(A,1) %// try all numbers of rows, in ascending order
    rows = nchoosek(1:size(A,1),nr).'; %'// all combinations of that nr rows
    for rr = rows %// try each combination of nr rows
        if any(all(eq1(rr,:),1)) & any(all(eq2(rr,:),1)) & any(all(eq3(rr,:),1))
            %// ",1" needed to make "all" by columns even if there's only one row
            result = rr; %// (overw)rite result (nr is larger now)
            break %// no need to keep trying combinations of rows for this nr
        end
    end
end
```

---

General Case: When you have more than 3 vectors, you can make these changes, so that your code looks concise -

```
%// Concatenate all V vectors into one
V = cat(1,V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,...)

%// Replace eq1, eq2 and eq3 calculations with this single calculation
eqa = squeeze(any(bsxfun(@eq,A,permute(V,[4 3 2 1])),3));

%// Replace the `IF` part with -
if all(any(all(eqa(rr,:,:),1)),3), result = rr, break, end ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! is it important the order [1 3 2]? what happen if V is 1x50?

Comment: That "`[1 3 2]`" is dimensions (1: rows, 2: columns, 3: slices), not entries of the vector. It will work for any row vector (i.e. size 1 x whatever)

Comment: what about 3 in any(bsxfun(@eq, A, permute(V1,...)), 3)? I apologize for my incompetence!

Comment: It also means third dimension of a 3D array. It doesn't restrict the size of vectors. You may want to look at the result of `permute(V1, [1 3 2])` and `bsxfun(@eq, A, permute(V1, [1 3 2]))` (without `any(...,3)`) to see how it works. It's interesting; `bsxfun` is a very powerful function

Comment: @LuisMendo I don't know anyone around me except myself who uses this term `slices` for the 3d dim, so it's interesting coming from you :) Well about this problem, I was looking for a fully vectorized approach until I gave up because I realized it's using the first match from V vectors. +1 for the bsxfun ;)

Comment: @Luis Mendo: if I use more than 3 vectors (Vk, k>3), this will increase the number of dimensions?

Comment: @bzak You would need to introduce `eq4` and `IF` part would reach your home probably, well if k is more than `10` maybe.

Comment: @Divakar: I'm talking about dimension in any(...,3)

Comment: @Divakar I've seen "slice" here on Stack Overflow. Probably from you, yes :-) Also "layer"

Comment: @bzak Divakar has explained it very well: add an `eq4` at the beginning and in the `if` condition. Dimensions won't change because of that, you can use as many vectors as you want. Not that by "dimensions" we mean "number of indices" (not "maximum value an index can take"; that would be size in a given dimension)

Comment: @LuisMendo Sorry I was really eager to make edits to a Luis Mendo  Solution ;) Please make sure that the edits looks good and produce the desired results ! :)

Comment: @bzak Check out the edits for case when you have more than 3 V vectors to deal with!

Comment: @Divakar: I applied your compact solution for more than 3 vectors, to the last example of my question and I got p = 2 instead of p = 1 !

Comment: @Divakar Nice generalization! I had thought of concatenating the vectors along 4th dim and applying `all(..., 4)` instead of the multiple `&`'s. I guess you handle it differently with the `permute`.

Comment: @Divakar ... and the `squeeze` to move 4th to 3rd. I like your way better

Comment: @LuisMendo I think your suggested way would be simpler because it would avoid `squeeze`. In the current generalized method, I think `squeeze` could be avoided if the dims are handled properly in the `IF` part. Well it works either way! :) I am just glad I didn't screw up your solution, because I was afraid of it when OP reported some bugs after my first edit to it :)