# How to replace a column of a specific value with zeros in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix like:

```
A=  
 1 2 7 4  
 3 2 8 5  
 2 2 9 6
```

and wants to zero a column with only 2's and get something like:

```
A=  
 1 0 7 4  
 3 0 8 5  
 2 0 9 6
```

Is there any clever way of doing this without two for loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `all` to find a column of all 2's

```
all2 = all( A == 2, 1 ); % check along first dim
A(:,all2 ) = 0; % make column zero
```

If you want to set to zero all columns that are of the same number (not only 2) you can use [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun) to assist

```
allSame = all( bsxfun( @eq, A, A(1,:) ), 1 );
A( :, allSame ) = 0;
```

Comment: you don't need `1` as the second operator for `all`, it's the default one.

Comment: @Divakar thank you for pointing it out. I have a personal tendency to explicitly define these default parameters. But you are correct, it can be omitted.

Comment: @Shai - I agree.  I like to explicitly put in the 1 to ensure no ambiguity and it allows for understanding for others who read my code.

Comment: Explicitly writing the default parameters can actually save you a lot of trouble. Suppose you want to sum all columns in a matrix, you could do `sum(A)`. However, if that matrix suddenly one day happens to only have one row, you would only get a single number back, causing bugs and possibly ruin your afternoon plans. Your working code stopped working after several weeks, and you didn't even change anything. (If you must ask: yes, it has happened)

Comment: @RobertP. if this bug ruined only the afternoon plans - then you are Okay, for me it would have taken an entire day to locate...

Comment: @Shai, hehe. I never said when I started debugging. It wasn't 4pm ;-)

Comment: @RobertP. oh you poor poor sod.

Comment: @RobertP. Great advice! Just happened to me [a few minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24808710/2586922). Luckily (?), it's happened so many times in the past that I've grown to identify that type of bug fast :-)